# Ionic: Authentication not persistent when merging to firebase v3

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm merging an ionic app from firebase v2 to firebase v3.

When I use the new (v3) firebase email/password login API, I am not authenticated have to log in every time the app is re-started.

The user should stay authenticated when first logged in into the app. Or at least this was default in the firebase v2 API.

How can I persist the login?

Thanks, 
Jørgen

Comment: By merging, you mean you've brought over code from v2 but using script Firebase 3 .js?

Comment: With firebase v3 the token never expires. Just be sure to only use the Firebase sdk v3

Comment: I only have firebase v3.1 in the project right now.

Comment: I log in, re-build the ionic app and when i try to log "firebase.auth().currentUser" it returns null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [`onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged). This function will be called any time there's a change in the authentication state.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    ... do other stuff
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    ... do other stuff
  }
});
```

If you are already logged in when you open your app, or you call `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, this function will be called and `user` will contain `firebase.auth().currentUser`.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. I'm gonna integrate it now :)